# What are the horizontal slots/tabs on the back of some saddles for?

Tags: saddle

Some saddles like Brooks have two tabs sticking down from the back, with a horizontal slot through each. What are these for? My guess is they are for certain kinds of saddle bags, but I don't really know. Is there a name for the slots (e.g. if I'm looking specifically for saddles that have that feature, what do I search for)?

Comment: Classic style saddle bags strap to them like Carradice: http://www.carradice.co.uk/index.php?page_id=category&url=original-saddlebags

Comment: ... or https://www.google.com/?q=brooks+saddle+bag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're totally right - they're for saddle bag straps.

[image]

I don't have a search term, but the word "roll" might get you further.